# Using if statement to call a function in Python

Tags: python, function, radians

Convert from Degree to radian and backward

```
def degree_to_radian(in_degree):
    angles_in_radian=(in_degree*pi)/180
    return(angles_in_radian)

def radian_to_degree(in_radian):
    angles_in_degree=in_radian*180/pi
    return(angles_in_degree)
```

I am required to write a program  angle converter(in num, in type)

if in_type is degree then it should use the first function and if radian the second function
and I shoud get somthing like this when running the program

> > > angle_converter (2.5 , ’Degree ’)

Degree 2.5 is equal to 0.04363323129985824 Radian

> > > angle_converter (2.5 , ’Radian ’)

Radian 2.5 is equal to 143.2394487827058 Degree

> > > angle_converter (2.5 , ’Float ’)

Not a valid type .

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: What language are you working on? Also show us your best moves first and come back if it does not work.

Comment: you're having trouble using an if statement to call a function in javascript?....? what have you tried?

Comment: It is python program

Comment: I tried to write this                                                                                       def angle_convenrter(in_num,in_type):  
  
   if in_type =='Degree'
     print('Degree',in_num,'equal to', degree_to_radian(in_degree):)  but I get error(syntax error)

Comment: @StarShine  it is python programing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language is JavaScript so use the following code else you can use same function for other language just else changing the syntax:

**Javascript:**

```js
    var angle_converter  = function(value,valueType){
       if (valueType=="degree"){
           return (value*Math.PI)/180;
       }else
       if (valueType=="radian"){
           return value*180/Math.PI;
       }
       else{
           return "Not a valid type!"
       }
    }

     console.log(angle_converter(2.5,"degree"))
     console.log(angle_converter(2.5,"radian"))
     console.log(angle_converter(2.5,"float"))
```

**Python:**

```
import math
def angle_converter(value,valueType):

    if valueType=="degree":
        return (value*math.pi)/180;
    else:
        if valueType=="radian":
            return value*180/math.pi;
        else:
            return "Not a valid type!"

#------------ USE: ------------
print(angle_converter(2.5,'degree'))  # >> 0.0436332312999
print(angle_converter(2.5,"radian"))  # >> 143.239448783
print(angle_converter(2.5,"float"))   # >> Not a valid type!
```

**[Live Demo](http://pythonfiddle.com/degree-radian/)**

Or this one:

```
import math
def angle_converter(value,valueType):
    if valueType=="degree":
        return degree_to_radian(value);
    else:
        if valueType=="radian":
            return radian_to_degree(value);
        else:
            return "Not a valid type!"

def degree_to_radian(in_degree):
    return((in_degree*math.pi)/180)

def radian_to_degree(in_radian):
    return(in_radian*180/math.pi)

print(degree_to_radian(2.5))  # >> 0.0436332312999
print(radian_to_degree(2.5))  # >> 143.239448783
print(angle_converter(2.5,'degree'))  # >> 0.0436332312999
print(angle_converter(2.5,"radian"))  # >> 143.239448783
print(angle_converter(2.5,"float"))   # >> Not a valid type!
```

Comment: what are a,b here? and you didn't use my previous two function as you wrote the conversion equation again.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with `Python` language but to write a `Python` version of my answer I forced to learn a few `Python` NOW! I changed and tested it. It works.

Comment: Actually i am new to python too and this is my first course in programing with python at university. Thanks any way

Comment: Yes, I guessed it, So tried to write it for you. I have not written even one line of Python code Before today but my experiences (about 15 year) in coding makes it easier to switch between languages, of-course If I have enough time. Also I added a link in my answer to Run the code online and see the result. Good luck...

Comment: it didn't work with me or maybe i am running it wrong but 2.5 is just example and still you didn't use the two previous function

Comment: @FarhanOmar, Run [live demo](http://pythonfiddle.com/degree-radian/). The result is: `0.0436332312999  143.239448783
Not a valid type!` like what you mentioned in your question. you can pass different values to the function too.

Comment: The last one is the one I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I read your updated question and guessed you want a version of the code that works by calling the functions that you added to your question. So I correct them and made a new version of the python code and appended it to my answer.

Comment: Runing the program should be as follows but i am just getting numbers so maybe we should put the print inside the if statment and something else I have my functions before so no need to put them again after the third function                                                                                                               
>>> angle_converter (2.5 , ’Degree ’)
Degree 2.5 is equal to 0.04363323129985824 Radian

>>> angle_converter (2.5 , ’Radian ’
Radian 2.5 is equal to 143.2394487827058 Degree

>>> angle_converter (2.5 , ’Float ’)

Not a valid type .